# Arithmatic conversion and store binary of a number

Tags: arithmetic, binary, decimal-expansion, fixed-points

I read this article:

[The Patriot Missile Failure](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Emignotte/IFT2425/Disasters.html)

I have one question: in above article it said that:

> It turns out that the cause was an inaccurate calculation of the time since boot due to computer arithmetic errors. Specifically, the time in tenths of second as measured by the system's internal clock was multiplied by 1/10 to produce the time in seconds.

Why it should multiply by `1/10` not `10`? if we have 0.1 second and it multiply by 1/10 then it equals to 0.01!

Have a good time

Comment: Maybe, exactly this was the error ( a humiliating error, if it was actually made ). But I do not know the history what actually went wrong. It could have be a lesson that it is not a good idea to automatize everything , but this lesson was not learnt.

Comment: @Peter, No. the problem was binary form of 1/10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is counting the number of tenths of seconds that have passed. One tenth of a second is $1$, two tenths of a second is $2$, three tenths of a second is $3$, etc. To convert that number to seconds you multiply by $1/10$.